# Read From A Json Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel

please i'm trying to get details of a json result from an API but getting (NaNa, NaNa).. Here is a break down of the code.

**Here's the API..**

```
public function lat($label)
        {
        $lat = Location::where('label', $label)->select('lat', 'lng')->get();

        $myJSON = json_encode($lat);

             return $myJSON;
    }
```

**Raw Data Result From API**

```
[{"lat":"5.475577","lng":"7.519388"}]
```

**User.js**

```
 var stateUrl = "/home/lat/" + $scope.locationState;

                $http({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: stateUrl
                }).then(
                  function successCallback(response) {

                    var source1 = new google.maps.LatLng(
                      response.data[1],
                      response.data[3]
                    );
```

Thank you..

Comment: Why are you accessing the first and third items in data?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Second and fourth, surely? ;-)

Comment: The response you've shown describes an array with a single entry, which is an object. But you're trying to access an object with a `data` property, taking its entries for keys 1 and 3. You probably want `response[0].lat` and `response[0].lng`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had thought that, but I changed because the 0 item could be “zeroth”. Typing it out now sounds silly

Comment: @evolutionxbox - :-) I've used zeroth too.